# Callback function with kendo grid refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and javascript as a whole, and recently discovered callback functions as a way to wait until one javascript function finishes prior to calling another. I want to wait until my Kendo grid finishes refreshing, then call a download method that redirects my application to a new URL. Is this possible? I tried to set it up like the code below, but that isn't working:

```
refreshGridThenLock(downloadAfterRefresh, selectedItems);

function refreshGridThenLock(callbackFunction, selectedItems){
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.read();
    grid.refresh();

    callbackFunction(grid, selectedItems);
}

function downloadAfterRefresh(){
    initiateFileDownload(selectedItems)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such event "grid ready". But you can try to use this example of `dataBound`event. take a look:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound